# how to get single generic type instead of entire collection

Tags: c#, generics, plugins, types, mef

When I go to load a DLL through `OpenFile`, the entire collection of plugins is being loaded to the assembly. I only need it to load a single plugin using the string name that was set in the `IPlugin` Interface.

How do I get it to only load the specific plugin I want to load?

```
public static class GenericPluginLoader<T>
{
    public static ICollection<T> LoadPlugins(string path)
    {
        string[] dllFileNames = null;

        if(Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            dllFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll");

            ICollection<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>(dllFileNames.Length);
            foreach(string dllFile in dllFileNames)
            {
                AssemblyName an = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(dllFile);
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(an);
                assemblies.Add(assembly);
            }

            Type pluginType = typeof(T);

           // Type pluginType = .GetType();
            ICollection<Type> pluginTypes = new List<Type>();
            foreach(Assembly assembly in assemblies)
            {
                if(assembly != null)
                {
                    Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();

                    foreach(Type type in types)
                    {
                        if(type.IsInterface || type.IsAbstract)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(type.GetInterface(pluginType.FullName) != null)
                            {
                                pluginTypes.Add(type);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            ICollection<T> plugins = new List<T>(pluginTypes.Count);
            foreach(Type type in pluginTypes)
            {
                T plugin = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                plugins.Add(plugin);
            }

            return plugins;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to prevent all the plugins from being loaded into the current appdomain? If so, use [Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom(v=vs.110).aspx), find the plugin you are looking for and only call Assembly.Load on that individual plugin.